Split column after getting multiple different CSV's into PowerBI/PowerQuery
Thank you in advance for you time and effort. I'm struggling with the following.
I want to load multiple different CSV files into PowerBI using Powerquery.These are separate files and `i do not want to combine them into 1 table.
I've managed to set up the connection but stuck as the stage right below. I have filtered down to the 4 files that I want to load and applied the Csv.Document function. However now all data is in 1 column and I would like to split them using the semicolon (';') but can't get it to work.

I have tried enriching the Csv.Document function but can't see how to solve the error:


It's already transfer to table not Binary. You don't need to use csv.document

Thanks I think I need to save the step after the first screenshot since that works. What would I put in the next step if I want to split the columns inside each of the Tables in column Content?

maybe you can try this
= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table.SplitColumn( Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content])),"col",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",")))


Table.SplitColumn

Thank you Ryan that is helpful however I think I made a mistake trying to get all the different files at once in 1 query. I've managed now in separate queries. Thanks!
